# Display: inline-block for a list

Tags: html, css

I want to create a list that should look like this

```
Few Clouds
Humidity: 33%
Wind: 5.1 mph
```

However, because I'm using JS to insert `<li>` elements , I have to pre-write some parts of the list like this (excluding the `[JS]` part):

```
[JS]
Humidity: [JS]%
Wind: [JS] mph
```

Here's my code to solve this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="clouds text-capitalize inline"> </li>
    <span class="inline">Humidity: </span><li class="wind inline"> </li><span class="inline">%</span>
    <span class="inline">Wind: </span><li class="humidity inline"> </li><span class="inline">mph</span>
 </ul>
```

and

```
.inline{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

but this results in (after the javascript plugs in data)

```
Few Clouds Humidity: 5.82 % Wind: 100mph
```

which is expected, but I dont know how to fix it so it looks like how I wanted in the first snippet. Ignore the other classes, they're bootstrap classes and classes for me to access them in javascript. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Don't use `inline-block` when you want elements on their own lines? Don't put `<span>` as a child of `<ul>`? `<li>Humidity: <span class="humidity"></span>%</li>`?

Comment: You don’t need to put display inline, but you have to put liststyle none

Comment: Why are you placing a span around your list element? Place the span inside of it.

Comment: @M H Rasel if I dont put display inline, then each element include the spans and li, will have their own line. Which I want each correlating span to share a line with a correlating span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** [**valid child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) of `<ul>` is `<li>`. Your `<span>` tags should go inside your `<li>` tags, not the other way around. I'd also recommend creating a second `<span>` tag inside each `<li>` to cover the JavaScript components. Considering `<span>` tags are **[inline by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)**, the pair of `<span>` tags will display next to each other on the same line.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('javascript');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = i;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="clouds text-capitalize inline">
    <span class="inline">Humidity: </span>
    <span class="javascript"></span></li>
  <li class="wind inline">
    <span class="inline">Wind %: </span>
    <span class="javascript"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="humidity inline">
    <span class="inline">mph: </span>
    <span class="javascript"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that if you want **all three** components to display on the same line, you could set the `<li>` elements to `display: inline-block` with:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

...Though that would essentially defeat the purpose of using an `<li>` element in the first place.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the inline class with the html span tags. Just add an additional li element for every line.

```css
.list-unstyled {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li class="clouds text-capitalize">Few Clouds</li>
 <li>Humidity: <span class="wind">5.82</span>%</li>
 <li>Wind: <span class="humidity">100 </span>mph</li>
 </ul>
```

[View On Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ppGlQfTYn66pxM4Usq5S?p=preview)